# How to maintain view instances created in onCreateView of Fragment in ViewPager when Resuming the fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

The story is that there are five fragments in the **ViewPager** and each fragment have to run an **AsyncTask** when it is appeared on ViewPager. I'm trying exactly the same as the correct answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21914808/how-to-handle-asynctasks-in-actionbaractivity-fragments-when-viewpager-is-used). I put my `AsyncTask` in `onResumeFragment` and it works fine. But the problem starts when I update the view after `AsyncTask` run successfully. Because the view(RecyclerView) I created inside **onCreateView** is being **null** when I update the dataset. I also tried `setRetainInstance(true)` inside `onActivityCreated`. It didn't work.

Here is my code,

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Tab & Pager

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_tab_content);
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    addPagerListener();
}

private void addPagerListener(){
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int newPosition) {
            FragmentLifecycle fragmentToShow = (FragmentLifecycle)adapter.getItem(newPosition);
            fragmentToShow.onResumeFragment();

            FragmentLifecycle fragmentToHide = (FragmentLifecycle)adapter.getItem(currentPosition);
            fragmentToHide.onPauseFragment();

            currentPosition = newPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0: return new HomeFragment();
            case 1: return new ArtistFragment();
            case 2: return new AlbumsFragment();
            case 3: return new CollectionsFragment();
            case 4: return new SavedFragments();
            default: return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

}
```

Here's my 2nd Fragment code, the rest fragments are blank so far.

```
public class ArtistFragment extends Fragment implements FragmentLifecycle{

@BindView(R.id.recyclerview_frag_artist)
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

@BindView(R.id.radioBtnAll_frag_artist)
RadioButton radioAll;

@BindView(R.id.radioBtnMale_frag_artist)
RadioButton radioMale;

@BindView(R.id.radioBtnFemale_frag_artist)
RadioButton radioFemale;

ArrayList<String> vocalistNameList;
Context context;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_artists, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(rootView.getContext());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    vocalistNameList = getDummyDS();
    mAdapter = new MyListAdapter(vocalistNameList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    radioAll.setChecked(true);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

private ArrayList<String> getDummyDS(){
    ArrayList<String> dataset = new ArrayList<>();
    dataset.add("test");
    dataset.add("test");
    dataset.add("test");
    dataset.add("test");
    dataset.add("test");
    dataset.add("test");
    dataset.add("test");
    return dataset;
}

private void getVocalistList(Gender gender){
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("action","query");
    params.put("list","allcategories");
    params.put("acprefix","Vocalist-");
    params.put("format","json");
    params.put("aclimit","5000");

    MyRestClient.get("", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
        ProgressDialog progress;
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(AppConstants.activity, "Please wait",
                        "Loading data..", true);
            progress.setCancelable(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            progress.dismiss();
            vocalistNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                JSONArray vocalListJsonArray = response.getJSONObject("query").getJSONArray("allcategories");
                for(int i=0; i<vocalListJsonArray.length(); i++){
                    String vocalListName = vocalListJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("*").replace("Vocalist-","");
                    vocalistNameList.add(vocalListName);
                }
                mAdapter = new MyListAdapter(vocalistNameList);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter); // <= RecyclerView is null and app is crashing
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
            progress.dismiss();
            Log.i("failure", "failed "+statusCode);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onPauseFragment() {
    Toast.makeText(AppConstants.applicationContext, "onPauseFragment():", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onResumeFragment() {
    getVocalistList(Gender.All);
    Toast.makeText(AppConstants.applicationContext, "onResumeFragment(): Artist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I have been trying to solve that problem since a week ago. Any idea?
(P.S I'm using [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) instead of `AsyncTask`)

Answer (score 1):

You have to do something like this:

```
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit([quantity of tabs that you would like to keep in memory]);
```

Take a look at this answer.
[ViewPager inside Fragment loses content when returning to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698557/viewpager-inside-fragment-loses-content-when-returning-to-it/24015733#24015733)

Comment: I think it works fine with few fragments. Mine is only 5 but I want a solution for future use.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the solution. It's very simple.

1. I removed implementation of the interface FragmentLifecycle.
2. Added the following method to each fragments.

   ```
   @Override
   public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if(isVisibleToUser && !isDataLoaded){
            getVocalistList(Gender.All);
            isDataLoaded = true;
        }
   }
   ```

It works like magic. I don't need to worry to lose `RecyclerView` instance since it was not being null when `setUserVisibleHint` method is called.

Comment: well, I'm not very convinced that this is "very simple", but thank you for your findings... I'm using ButterKnife and I see that my RecyclerView is being dismissed and a new one is created every time I return to the Fragment inside the ViewPager... Where can I find that `FragmentLifecycle` interface? and also, why set the isDataLoaded flag to true before the AsyncTask is finished with loading data?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, here you go. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24386516/1976608